# Show that $\{f_n \} \to f$ in $L^p(E)$ iF $\{f_n\}$ belongs to and is bounded as a subset of $L^{p+\theta} (E)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Assume $E$ has finite measure and $1 \leq p < \infty$. Suppose $\{ f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions that converges pointwise a.e. on $E$ to $f$. For $1 \leq p < \infty$, show that $\{f_n \} \to f$ in $L^p(E)$ if there is a $\theta > 0$ such that $\{f_n\}$ belongs to and is bounded as a subset of $L^{p+\theta} (E)$.}

**My attempt:**

We have to prove two things: $\{f_n\}$ and $f$ belongs to $ L^{p}$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(E)$.

For the first part: consider $\theta>0$ exists and $f_n \in L^{p+\theta}(E)$ we know that if $1\leq p \leq p+ \theta< \infty$ and $\{f_n \} \in L^{p+\theta}(E)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\{f_n \} \in L^{p}(E)$

(I used for this the following: Corollary 3: Let $E$ be a measurable set of finite measure and $1 \leq p1 < p2 \leq \infty$. Then $L^{p_2}(E) \subseteq L^{p_1}(E)$. Furthermore,
$||f||_{p_1} \leq  c||f||_{p_2} $ for all $f \in L^{p_2}(E)$)

How do I prove that $f \in L^p(E)$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(E)$

Comment: I put an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2355395/389981).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: 1. To prove $f \in L^p,$ use Fatou's lemma. 2. For $f_n\to f$ in $L^p,$ use Egorov to see $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $E$ save for a smallish subset of $E.$

Comment: Is it possible to introduce dyadic decomposition to solve this? (I mean, for example, decompose $x=\sum_{n\ge0}\phi_n(x)$ for $x\ge0$ where $\phi_0(x)=\min(1,x)$ and $\phi_n(x)=\min(2^n,x)-\min(2^{n-1},x)$ and extend them to odd functions). In addition, I think the original statement is true if we replace convergence a.e. by convergence by measure, or even some weaker condition.

Comment: Dyadic stuff, I don't know. I doubt it's as easy as what my hints point to. Convergence in measure would be enough because some subsequence converges a.e. Fatou then gives $f\in L^p.$ If $f_n \not \to f$ in  $L^p,$ then there is a subseq $\int |f_{n_k}-f|^p  $ bounded away from $0$, go to a further subsequence that converges a.e., and then you contradict the result already obtained.

Comment: Show that $f  \in L^p(E)$
$$||f||_p^p =\int_E |f|^p \leq \lim\inf\limits_{n \to \infty} \int|f_n|^p \leq M^p$$
$$\Rightarrow ||f|| \leq M $$
$$\Rightarrow f \in L^p$$

Comment: Long ago I did this exercise, and essentially it's related to uniform integrability. Now I'm just trying another harder viewpoint, which is maybe useful in many sense, such as estimation a priori in PDE, and interpolations between Sobolev spaces. (So I don't care about easiness.) The phenomenon that bounded in an index and convergence in another index, seems pretty common to deduce some regularity of weak solutions.

Comment: Another comment: in order to prove for convergence in measure, you needn't go back to convergence a.e. In fact, do a truncation in value: for small values we use dominated convergence theorem, and for big values we use Tchebychef inequality.

Comment: See my answer for hard-analytic viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a (hard-analytic) comment to zhw's answer. As he had shown, $f\in L^p$. We note that since $E$ has finite measure, the topology of convergence in measure is induced by $d_m(f,g)=\int_E\min(\lvert f-g\rvert,1)$. What we need to do is to interpolate $\lVert f\rVert_{L^q}$ between $\lVert f\rVert_{L^p}$ and $\lVert f\rVert_m:=\int_E\min(\lvert f\rvert,1)$ for $1\le q<p$. Write $f=f_0+f_\infty$, where
$$f_0(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x)&x\le1\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$f_\infty(x)=\begin{cases}
0&x\le1\\
f(x)&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Let $\alpha_0=\int_{\lvert f\rvert\le1}1$, $\alpha_\infty=\lVert f_\infty\rVert_{L^1}$, $\beta_0=\lVert f_0\rVert_{L^p}^p$, $\beta_\infty=\lVert f_\infty\rVert_{L^p}^p$. It follows from Hölder's inequality that $\lVert f_0\rVert_{L^q}^q\le\alpha_0^{1-q/p}\beta_0^{q/p}$ and $\lVert f_\infty\rVert_{L^q}^q\le\alpha_\infty^{(1-q/p)/(p-1)}\beta_\infty^{(q-1)/(p-1)}$ (the later is also known as [interpolation of $L^p$ spaces](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/). Hence we can get an estimation of $\lVert f\rVert_{L^q}$ by $\alpha_0,\alpha_\infty,\beta_0,\beta_\infty$. Since $\alpha_0,\alpha_\infty\le\lVert f\rVert_m$ and $\beta_0,\beta_\infty\le\lVert f\rVert_{L^p}^p$, we obtain what we want. Moreover, we can optimize the estimation by a wise choice of $\alpha_0,\alpha_\infty$ and $\beta_0,\beta_\infty$ subject to $\alpha_0+\alpha_\infty=\lVert f\rVert_m$ and $\beta_0+\beta_\infty=\lVert f\rVert_{L^p}^p$.